# Isotopic homeomorphisms of surface induces same map on the space of ends

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, surfaces

Let $\Sigma$ be a non-compact orientable connected two-manifold without boundary. Let $f,g\colon \Sigma\to \Sigma$ be two homeomorphisms. Suppose there is a homotopy $H\colon \Sigma\times [0,1]\to \Sigma$ from $f$ to $g$ such that $H(-,t)\colon \Sigma\to \Sigma$ is a homeomorphism for each $t\in [0,1]$.

Now, $f,g$ induce maps $\mathcal E(f),\mathcal E(g)\colon \mathcal E(\Sigma)\to \mathcal E(\Sigma)$, where $\mathcal E(\Sigma)$ denotes the space of ends of $\Sigma$.

> Is it true that $\mathcal E(f)=\mathcal E(g)$?
>
> If the above question has a false answer, then do I need to consider
> some restriction, like $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ is (in)finitely-generated?

Of course, if $H$  itself is a proper map, then $\mathcal E(f)=\mathcal E(g)$, for any $\Sigma$.

Comment: Isn't an isotopy a proper map?

Comment: @Random - those maps are not isotopic because one preserves orientation and the other does not.

Comment: My bad! I forgot the word orientation-preserving: If two orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of a surface are homotopic relative to the boundary, then they are isotopic relative to the boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the induced maps $\mathcal{E}(f)$ and $\mathcal{E}(g)$ are equal.  This is because two isotopic transversely oriented separating circles in $\Sigma$ determine the same subset of $\mathcal{E}(\Sigma)$ and because such subsets give a basis for the topology of $\mathcal{E}(\Sigma)$.

Comment: @Random - those maps are homotopic, but not isotopic.

Comment: My bad! I forgot the word orientation-preserving: If two orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of a surface are homotopic relative to the boundary, then they are isotopic relative to the boundary.

Comment: I have a question? So, an isotopy (defined as a homotopy through homeomorphisms) between surfaces may not be proper but should fix ends. Am I right?

Comment: @Random - What is an example of a non-proper isotopy?

Comment: @Random - Also, IMHO you should not delete your comments once the thread has grown around them. (Yes, they were wrong, but in a non-trivial way.  Learning is happening!)

Comment: I got this paper recently https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1963-014-04/S0002-9939-1963-0181989-2/S0002-9939-1963-0181989-2.pdf Also, I won't delete comments in future

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps you should add as another answer.  Namely, isotopies need not be proper in general (I think this is shown by Example 1.1 in your reference) but are proper for manifolds (by Theorem 1.2).  Thus the isotopy $H$ given by the OP is proper.